# Jquery animations working correctly in IE7 but not in IE8?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, scrollto

—Please, be gentle.

On the same page I have https://github.com/Wilto/Dynamic-Carousel and a custom script I made with jquery and jquery scrollto:

```
$('#bio_link').click(function(event){
    if (event.preventDefault)  {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
       event.returnValue = false;
    }
    $('#bio').slideDown('slow', function() {
        $.scrollTo('#bio', 300);
    });
});
```

The Wilto Dynamic-Carousel works fine in every browser including IE7, but not in IE8: the images change but there's no animation.
The scrollto works fine the second time you click on it but on the first try it just jumps where it should go without any animation.

Any ideas?

Maybe it can be of help: it works in IE8 in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

The IE8 specific CSS must be the issue. Look for the following things:

- `position:static`
- `style=` on parent element of `#bio`